# how can i using mix(Elixir) install package install to system?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I just want run IEx to require this package, I do not want create a mix project and into the deps.

For example, `gem install bundle`

How do I do this?

Comment: can you try "mix archive.install ". I dont exactly know how to use it nor do i say it is the solution. for help try "mix help archive.install"

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, `mix archive.install` is useful to install archives that will provide mix tasks.
What you could do is to put all the .beam files in a repository that will be specified at iex/elixir startup (with the `-pa $CUSTOMPATH` option).
This will load the .beam files during elixir startup.

For instance, in the `elixir` shell script, there is this line:

`exec "$ERL_PATH" -pa "$SCRIPT_PATH"/../lib/*/ebin $ELIXIR_ERL_OPTIONS $ERL -extra "$@"`

You can add an additional `-pa ~/.local/ebin" to load those .beam file

Comment: @Yingce I'm commenting this answer to link a blog post I recently wrote about that: https://blog.crypto-keupone.eu/an-iex-shell-with-preloaded-libraries.html